# hide and show dynamically created paragraphs using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a Sharepoint site that is dynamically grabbing a name and description from a list.

```
var name = $(this).attr('ows_Title');  //This is the internal storage name in SP
var comments = $(this).attr('ows_MetaInfo').match(/^_Comments:SW\|(.*)$/m);
```

I am then taking these vars and feeding them into an empty div on my page (the div is called 'docList')

```
        var item = "<a class='docLinks' href='http:path/to/the/doc/" + name + "'>" 
+ title + "</a><br><p><span class='description' id='para_" + i + "'>"
    + comments + "</span></p><br>";
        $('#docList').append(item);
```

I am trying to make it so the 'comments' i.e. description of the item, appear on hover below the name of the item.

I have tried various iterations on this theme:

```
     $('#docList a').hover(function(){
          $(this).child().css({'display':'block'})},
          function(){
              $(this).child().css({'display':'none'});
         });
```

I know that I can access the hover event, because I coded in some simple alerts, and they were fine.

Originally, I tried giving each 'comments' its ownid (as you can see), but got tripped up in getting the index value. I then decided to try to do this using

```
      $(this).children('.description').css({'display':'block'});
```

But no luck. Am I close? Where am I screwing up the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).nextUntil('p').next().find('.description').hide()

$(this).nextUntil('p').next().find('.description').show()
```

and you don't need `id` for this

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, phantasm..... I should have mentioned, the descriptions are already hidden, so I flipped your code thusly:

             $('#docList a').hover(function(){
                  $(this).nextUntil('p').next().find('.description').show();}
                  ,function(){
                     $(this).nextUntil('p').next().find('.description').hide();
             });
And it isn't working. Where did I screw this one up?

Comment: check http://jsfiddle.net/jV5KM/ , everyting is fine (I've added `last()`, but it's not necessary)

Comment: I really appreciate you taking that kind of time... For some reason I can't get the damn thing to work in my CEWP in SP though.... Not sure what the f is going on....

Comment: I'm such a boob.... I had copied and pasted (boo) a reference to jquery 1.3.2.... Just had to update my reference. Thanks a bunch!